# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-18] Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving this error:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/XXX/FlutterDev/XXX_app/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-18]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
```

Saw one other answer for the solution:

1. I tried checking my androidxml for android:installLocation="preferExternal" but I do not have it
2. Trying to wiping data off emulator

But it did not work